# Error with uploading large files to windows azure storage using WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, file-upload, azure

I have a sample web application through which i am consuming WCF service, which is intended to upload large capacity[upto 50mb] file to azure storage, I am getting error saying The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.

This my sample Wcf service code:
Interface [IService1.cs]

```
namespace FileService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void UploadFile(Stream inputstream);

    }

}
```

Service1.svc

```
public class Service1 : IService1
        {
           public void UploadFile(Stream inputstream)
            {

                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

                // Create the blob client.
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");

                // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("testfile");

                 blockBlob.UploadFromStream(inputstream);
            }
        }
```

Test.aspx page to consume the wcf service

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.IService1 clientUpload = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        clientUpload.UploadFile(FileUpload1.FileContent);
    }
```

web.config file in wcf

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <!--  To collect diagnostic traces, uncomment the section below or merge with existing system.diagnostics section.
        To persist the traces to storage, update the DiagnosticsConnectionString setting with your storage credentials.
        To avoid performance degradation, remember to disable tracing on production deployments.
  <system.diagnostics>     
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="AzureLocalStorage" type="FileService.AzureLocalStorageTraceListener, FileService"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources> 
   </system.diagnostics> -->
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

web.config File in web application

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097150"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:50980/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config check the binding you are using and in the transport section, add the maxReceivedMessageSize.

For instance if you are using httpTransport.

```
<httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
```

Comment: I added <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MultiFileService"   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

Comment: Still its saying The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.

Comment: @mahesh Where have you added this? at the WCF web.config or at the web app web.config?

Comment: @mahesh In the web app, check the web.config, cause whenever you add service reference, it creates a binding too. modify the bindings there as well.

Comment: I added following change in web app (web.config) file  <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"  />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:50980/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>

Comment: Its saying The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.I am missing any other config settings?

Comment: @mahesh you didn't need to add this. Please remove. When you added service reference it created a binding section for you, thats all you need. in the binding it created simply add the maxReceivedMessageSize and everything will work.

Comment: ya now i have only the following change <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings> ,  still its throwing error

Comment: @mahesh what about the <client> section? you needed that. can you post your config here? the entire <system.ServiceModel> section, add it to your answer please.

Comment: @mahesh And try to make sure your service is still running without issue. Try access the Service1.svc from a browser to be sure it still loads without throwing errors.

Comment: Ya service is perfectly running in the browser, its the issue with consuming wcf service for large files